# Apache CORS headers for docker

Tags: angular, apache, docker, cors, virtualhost

On my server I have two docker containers. One is docker Registry, and the other is Angular app that access first containers endpoint.

Docker registry has mapped port 5000 and is proxied through Apache's virtual host to domain docker.mydomain.com. Angular app has port 5002 and is proxied to dockerhub.mydomain.com

I set up a virtual host file for my docker registry like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName docker.mydomain.com
        Redirect permanent / https://docker.mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias docker.mydomain.com
        ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com

        # Headers required for docker registry to work
        Header set Host "docker.mydomain.com"
        Header always set "Docker-Distribution-Api-Version" "registry/2.0"
        Header onsuccess set "Docker-Distribution-Api-Version" "registry/2.0"
        RequestHeader set X-forwarded-Proto "https"

        # Settings CORS headers
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept"
        Header always set Vary "Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method"

        # SSL settings
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/docker.mydomain.com/cert.pem"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/docker.mydomain.com/privkey.pem"
        SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/docker.mydomain.com/chain.pem"

        # Reply to all OPTIONS requests with 200
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off

        # Proxy request to localhost:5000 and check authentication
        <Location "/">
                ProxyPass http://localhost:5000/
                ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:5000/
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
                AuthName "Registry Authentication"
                AuthType basic
                AuthUserFile "/opt/docker-registry-htpasswd/.registry-htpasswd"
                # Allow reading to all users, but pushing images only for certain user
                <Limit GET HEAD>
                        Require valid-user
                </Limit>
                <Limit POST PUT DELETE PATCH>
                        Require user myuser
                </Limit>
        </Location>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/docker-registry-error.log
        LogLevel warn

</VirtualHost>
```

My Angular app that is in another docker is served with nginx image with following configuration:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 4200;
        server_name  localhost;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I open my Angular app at dockerhub.mydomain.com and it tries to call API from docker.mydomain.com I get error related with CORS headers:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://docker.mydomain.com/v2' from 
origin 'https://dockerhub.mydomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:4200' that is 
not equal to the supplied origin.
```

As far as I know if Allow-Origin header is set to * it means that it is set to the request's Origin, which is set to https://dockerhub.mydomain.com but instead Allow-Origin is set to localhost:4200 - What could the problem here be?

Also, the Angular app is always making requests to docker.mydomain.com and never to localhost address.

Comment: Basically there is mismatch in headers. You have to look at your requests, and find who is setting wrong URL `http://localhost:4200`. On the other hand, I would suggest to reverse proxy from your `nginx` to docker registry (like point `/api/docker-registry`), so that you would not bother with CORS at all. Will be like `browser -> nginx -> docker registry` or `browser -> nginx -> apache -> docker registry`. And then from Angular app, send API requests without domain to `/api/docker-registry/*`. Also simpler for clients.

Comment: My nginx only serves angular app, it does not make any other requests or such. workflow is such: user requests dockerhub -> apache redirects to docker container with nginx -> ngingx serves angular app -> angular app requests docker.mydomain.com -> apache redirects to docker container with docker registry -> docker registry replies. what tool do you recommend to supervise requests?

Comment: As per your flow, make such that your angular app request your nginx on specific path, which is then configured as reverse proxy to your docker.mydomain.com. i.e. don't let browser with your angular app to go deliberately to another domain (which is docker.mydomain.com), but only through nginx (which serves angular app) as reverse proxy.

Comment: For instance, add in your nginx with angular application next to `location /`:
`location /api/docker { proxy_pass http://docker.mydomain.com/; }`
And the let application go to `/api/docker` without domain prefix. There is many examples in the internet how to set reverse proxy with nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copying nginx.conf to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` I copied the configuration file to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

Then I also shortened conf file a bit:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Now I get properly set CORS headers in all browsers