# Docker loads login screen, but not starting node server.js - MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

Here's most up-to-date configuration since adding bounty: [Configuration](http://pastebin.com/VDC1SdG1)

`UPDATE:` It looks like it's getting a cors error when clicking login, which is most likely causing the issue. I've read in other posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53250811/4350389) that I need to update nginx.conf. I haven't been able to figure out how to update said file since it's already dockerized assuming this is the solution to my problem. Also could be related to not referencing cosmodb in docker-comopose, but when I add this

```
    cosomsdb:
        build: ./backend
        ports:
        - "10255:10255"
```

I get cors error still. `10255` is cosmosdb port

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/api/user/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
2
ERROR 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/user/login", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/api/user/login: 0 Unknown Error", error: error }
core.js:6014:19
```

I'm trying to build a MEAN stack docker image, but every time I run it, it says

```
Error: Cannot find module '../backend/middleware/check-auth'
```

I don't think it's copying my files to the container correctly. I've been going through forums, but haven't been able to find a solution. I appreciate any help!

Dockerfile

```
FROM node

MAINTAINER Phil

WORKDIR /src

COPY . .

RUN npm install

RUN npm install -g nodemon

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
        - "/Users/Phil/Documents/myapp/myapp-docker/frontend/dist:/usr/share/nginx/html"
    node:
        build: ./backend
        ports:
        - "3000:3000"
```

backend package.json

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.612.0",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.8",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "create-hash": "^1.2.0",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.11",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^2.0.3",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "multer-s3": "^2.9.0"
  }
}
```

server.js file

```
const app = require("./app");
const debug = require("debug")("node-angular");
const http = require("http");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var redis = require("redis");

var env = require("dotenv").config();


const normalizePort = val => {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    e;
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
};

const onError = error => {
  if (error.syscall !== "listen") {
    throw error;
  }
  const bind = typeof port === "string" ? "pipe " + port : "port " + port;
  switch (error.code) {
    case "EACCES":
      console.error(bind + " requires elevated privileges");
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case "EADDRINUSE":
      console.error(bind + " is already in use");
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
};
console.log("process.env.COSMODDB_USER");
console.log(env.COSMODDB_USER);
mongoose
  .connect(
    "mongodb://" +
      process.env.COSMOSDB_HOST +
      ":" +
      process.env.COSMOSDB_PORT +
      "/" +
      process.env.COSMOSDB_DBNAME +
      "?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb",
    {
      auth: {
        user: process.env.COSMODDB_USER,
        password: process.env.COSMOSDB_PASSWORD
      }
    }
  )
  .then(() => console.log("Connection to CosmosDB successful"))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

const onListening = () => {
  const addr = server.address();
  const bind = typeof port === "string" ? "pipe " + port : "port " + port;
  debug("Listening on " + bind);
};

const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || "3000");
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || port);

var server = app.listen(app.get("port"), function() {
  debug("Express server listening on port " + server.address().port);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the content of app.js file? Since the `server.js` looks fine but it requires `app.js`, I suspect that there is something not right with that file!

Answer (score 0):

If you omit the version of node in Dockerfile, latest will be used. Check the version that you are using on your local machine and specify it (also, specifying the versions in Dockerfile is a good practice)

Comment: I changed it to ```FROM node:10.16.3``` but I get the same error

Comment: Have you tried to run the same command in your machine? That work?

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you mean. I run ```docker-compose up --build``` or ```docker-compose up``` but it throws error either way using this configuration: https://pastebin.com/C3dtxzqV

Comment: I mean if you run npm install, npm install -g nodemon and npm start locally

Comment: The docker container now loads up my app to the login screen, but doesn' let me login. If I run nodemon server.js locally outside the docker container than my app inside the docker container can login

Comment: I added an ```UPDATE:``` above

Comment: The correct way to do that is adding nodemon as devDependency in package.json. check the version you run locally (that works) and install it on your project using npm install nodemon@{version} --save-dev

Comment: nodemon version 2.02. I'm not really sure what you mean. I have two package.json files. One in the backend folder and one in the frontend. This could be another issue with my setup. IDK. I did what I think you meant and added the devDependencies section to backend package.json, which wasn't there before and did the npm install nodemon@2.0.2, but same issue with CORS error. updated backend package.json: https://pastebin.com/df3sYaUL

Comment: CORS Is ocurring because the host and port are different between frontend and backend. you may setup a reverse proxy on nginx

Answer (score 0):

Hey Could you please check your .dockerignore file and see that you're not omitting the files you really want in the container while building?

Comment: The only thing in my .dockerignore is ```node_modules```

Comment: I believe that the location of the file read is a bit wrong..because the location should be /src/middleware/check-auth.. but it's going to backend which is not actually added here.

Directory structure should be:
```
/src
  |_ middleware/check-auth
  |_ all other files.

```

Comment: I believe you're correct, but I have no idea what to change to make it work.

Comment: can you paste your package.json? I guess fixing your package.json will be a good start or you can supply the `--prefiex /src` after npm start

Comment: The package.json is above unless you mean the frontend package.json: https://pastebin.com/yFQi0gU3

Comment: I think the --prefix option of npm start will be a good start.

Comment: By doing this: https://pastebin.com/VzpVBpCv  I was able to get to the end of the ```docker-compose up --build``` When I go to localhost, I get 403 forbidden though. Here's the log https://pastebin.com/4eEfQAmR .

Comment: The error I'm getting when I visit localhost ```/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory),```

Comment: I think `/Users/Phil/Documents/myapp/myapp-docker/frontend/dist` this path might be wrong or has a typo somewhere. Because if we mount `/doesnot/exist/path` to  `/usr/share/nginx/html` that will still work. Docker will create the path `/doesnot/exist/path` for you and mount it. Please double check your path.

Comment: Here's a pic of my directory https://postimg.cc/cvbZxr5X   I've tried the following paths https://pastebin.com/UwWbNaJc    . I noticed that the build was grabbing from a cache so with the following paths configured. I entered ```docker-compose build --no-cache``` followed by ```docker-compose up``` My original path didn't directly point into folder with index.html as you can see from directory image, but with it configured with the following paths from pastebin link, I'm still getting 403 forbidden when entering ```localhost``` into address bar so something isn't pointing right still?

Comment: Yeah, so the path that we should use is this `c:/Users/Phil/Documents/myapp/myapp-docker/frontend/dist`. The path that we were using before wasn't fully qualified.

Comment: That was one of the paths I've already tried that gives me the forbidden page...

Comment: so can you please make sure that index.html file is present in the directory that you're trying to mount.

Comment: I got it working with the following path in both the frontend DockerFile and docker-compose.yaml file ```C:\Users\Phil\Documents\myapp\myapp-docker\frontend\dist\myapp://usr/share/nginx/html``` My app now loads the login screen, but it doesn't seem to be connecting outside docker container. I have an .env file that makes the connections to mongodb. Do I have to do something to make that part work?

Comment: I've noticed that while it doesn't login when launching docker. The docker container will login if I start nodemon server.js from my project outside the docker container. I'm pretty sure the problem lies with this line the start script inside backend package.json. I think it's trying to execute that start line, but within the frontend folder in backend package.json. I could be wrong. I'm trying to figure out how to get docker-compose to look in correct location. Currently it fails with ```node server.js``` I think because of wrong package.json it's looking at.

Comment: Can you update your question to show your `require`s or `import`s in app.js and server.js. Are you building from your `docker-compose.yaml`? I am assuming that your docker-compose file is in the parent directory of backend?

Comment: Here's the most up-to-date configuration I have: pastebin.com/VDC1SdG1 I am building from the docker-compose file. I added the server.js file above –

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your importing `'../backend/middleware/check-auth'` in app.js? If so, change you import path to `'./backend/middleware/check-auth'`. Your compose file and container seem fine. This looks more like a path issue for your module import.

Comment: If I change it to only one ```.``` then I get ```Cannot find module './backend/middleware/check-auth'``` when trying to run locally. Also didn't work in docker container

Answer (score 0):

For the `CORS` problem, try adding the lib [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) in your server.js like this:

```
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: [ 'http://localhost:3000' ]
}))
```

Lets see if it helps.
By the way, `dotenv` should always come first (;

Comment: I added your code and also did ```npm install cors``` since it couldn't find module when testing. Updated server.js file: https://pastebin.com/VX3VC0Ga  but when I did docker-compose up and tried to login, I got ```Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/api/user/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).```

Comment: What is the frontend using to do the requests? Axios or Fetch? Can we see this code too?

Comment: Apparently, `CORS request did not succeed` means the request has not even reached the backend, as seen here[1]. This may be due to many reasons, but I'm guessing it is a problem in the communication between frontend and backend.

Does the backend has any SSL?


[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed

Comment: Also, whats your Angular version?

Comment: ```Angular CLI: 8.3.6 and

Angular: 8.2.8```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208076/discussion-between-rodurico-and-user6680).